# change format number msgbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

please help me to change a format number for this msgbox
i need the format number like standard for example : 3,456.79

````
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("1")
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [amount] FROM qicard;")
MsgBox "total salary : " & DSum("amount", "[1]"), vbQuestion, "salary"```
````

Comment: Look at the `Format()` function

Comment: thank you its work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Format` function to get the number displayed correctly:

```
Format(DSum("amount","[1]"),"#,##0.00")
```

Also, If you are just using `DSum`, and there is no other code, then you don't need to use a recordset or a querydef.

Regards,

Comment: thank you very very much for your help bro @Applecore